# dragging a container with clickable children as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling

I have a container that has children that will need CLICK events registered to them.  The container is draggable and the children shouldn't interfere with the drag or be triggered by it.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to accomplish this.  Any help is appreciated.

This is the closest I can come, by removing any click handlers if the object has been moved.  This seems messy though

```
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragit);
box.circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, circleclick);


function dragit(e:MouseEvent) 
{
   box.startDrag();
   box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdrag);
}


function stopdrag(e:Event) 
{
if(box.x != 0)
    {
        box.circle.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, circleclick);
    }
    box.stopDrag();
}

function circleclick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace('clicked');
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code or pseudo code based on what you have already tried?

Comment: CLICK is MOUSE_DOWN + MOUSE_UP. However, when you register for either MOUSE_DOWN or MOUSE_UP, you can't get CLICK anymore. If you have a MOUSE_MOVE that is larger than a certain distance (you'll have to decide what, based on your project) before MOUSE_UP, you have a drag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following works for me, you can drag the container from anywhere including the children, I added a suppress click flag to prevent the clicks if the container is dragged from a child you might use that or not depending on your application.

```
package 
{
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        private var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var suppressClick:Boolean = false;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            container.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
            container.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            container.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(container);

            container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);

            var child:Sprite = new Sprite();
            child.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00, 1);
            child.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            child.graphics.endFill();
            child.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onChildClick);
            child.x = 100;
            child.y = 100;
            container.addChild(child);


        }

        private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            suppressClick = false;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
            container.startDrag();
        }

        private function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            suppressClick = true;
        }

        private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
            container.stopDrag();
        }

        private function onChildClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if(!suppressClick)
                trace("child clicked");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So you're only startDrag if the mouse has moved after the MOUSE_DOWN and once it moves you set the supressClick flag and the click function only fires its goods if the suppressClick is still false... I think I can make that work.

Comment: Well I called `startDrag` as soon as the mouse is down, but if the cursor doesn't move then no dragging happens and when when mouse up is received stop drag is called so nothing is dragged.